# Which is better in perfermance between Dot and Bracket Notation in property accessors of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In an interview, I was asked the question as described in the title. I think the interviewer wanted to ask about the underlying principles of property accessors in js. So what I want to know is the perfemance and principles instead of difference.

Bracket Notation

```js
const a = { b: { c: 'Bracket Notation' } }
console.log(a['b']['c'])
```

Dot Notation

```js
const a = { b: { c: 'Dot Notation' } }
console.log(a.b.c)
```

Comment: i guess use bracket notation when trying to access using dynamic key names

Comment: Trick question, the answer is to profile your code and find other things that are much more worthwhile optimizing. If your code is running too slow, this choice is unlikely to have the most significant contribution to execution time.

Comment: also if your object has field names that have spaces you are pretty much resticted to brackets

Comment: You should ask ChatGPT questions like this before coming here, because it will give you the textbook appropriate interview response the interviewer was looking for.  I'm downvoting because you don't seem to have done this basic research effort yet.  Asking for "the principles" is perhaps lacking focus.  Spoiler: the performance difference is negligible - go for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key differences between *[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation)* and *[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)* is in their ability to access dynamically generated properties.

The dynamic property access capability is a significant advantage of *[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)* and is essential when you need to compute the property name at runtime. It allows you to access properties that you couldn't access using *[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation)*, such as properties with spaces or special characters, or properties whose names are stored in variables.

Performance-wise, there used to be a minor difference between the two in older JavaScript engines, with *[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation)* being slightly faster. However, modern JavaScript engines have optimized both notations to a point where the difference is negligible.